# Why $\mathbb R$ is not complete with the metric $d(x,y)=|\phi(x)-\phi(y)|$ where $\phi(x)=\frac{x}{1+|x|}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

> Suppose $d(x,y)=|\phi(x)-\phi(y)|$ where $\phi(x)=\frac{x}{1+|x|}$. Prove that $\mathbb  R$ is not complete with this metric.

This is exercise 12 from chapter 1 from Rudin's Functional Analysis.

I tried to find a Cauchy sequence for this metric that does not converge but I couldn't.

Comment: @RobinGoodfellow I tried to find a cauchy sequence for this metric that not converge but I couldn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Try with $x_n=n$. It is a $d$-Cauchy sequence but not $d$-convergent.